# Use RPi3 as hub for USB-connected devices?

Tags: networking

I want to provide ethernet-over-USB to ipads and iphones connected to my RPi3 using USB-to-lightning cables, with the RPi connected to my LAN using a regular LAN cable. How can I set this up?
Thanks!

Comment: As neither  iPads nor iPhones have Ethernet this seems pointless.

Comment: iOS devices are able to use ethernet via USB. Just look up "Belkin Ethernet + Power Adapter with Lightning Connector".
What I want to do is use my RPi as the network 'hub' for multiple iOS devices.

Comment: Ethernet is a Link Layer protocol.

Comment: Do you mean [this one](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/p-f8j227/)?

Comment: Yep, that type of device.